# xslt tokenize() and "Not a node item" error

Tags: xml, xslt

I use tokenize() function to iterate through set of values, but then I try to use this values in template calls - "Not a node item" error occurs.

```
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($edge_pairs,';')">
                <xsl:if test="number(string-length(.)) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:variable name="c_row" select="." as="xs:string"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="src" select="substring-before($c_row,':')" as="xs:string"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="dst" select="substring-after($c_row,':')" as="xs:string"/>
                        <xsl:call-template name="links">
                            <xsl:with-param name="src1" select="$src"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="dst1" select="$dst"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>        
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

this is raw that triggers error:

```
<xsl:for-each select="root()//gml:edge[@source = $src1 and @target = $dst1 or  @source = $dst1 and @target = $src1]">
```

Comment: Please post enough code (XML + XSLT) to enable us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the code that triggers the error is in the named template `links`, then the issue is you are no longer in the context of the source XML document. You are inside an `xsl:for-each` on a tokenised string, so the context is an atomic value (i.e. a single string).

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(a,';')">
```

This means the root() function will not work because the context is a string, and not a node in a document object.

The solution is define a global variable (i.e. a child of `xsl:stylesheet`, outside of any templates), that references the root:

```
<xsl:variable name="root" select="root()" />
```

Then you can change your `xsl:for-each` that is failing to this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$root//gml:edge[(@source = $src1 and @target = $dst1) or (@source = $dst1 and @target = $src1)]">
```